# Как получить данные из запроса от пользоваетля

Tags: python, django

В функции-контроллере указывается параметр request, который является запросом пользователя, и после, в теле котроллера, возможно обратится к нему и получить какие-то данные от пользователя, к примеру, проверить, авторизирован ли пользователь на сайте - `request.user.is_authenticated`. Можно ли в классе-конроллере, допустим, PasswordChangeView, обратиться к запросу пользователя, чтобы также проверить, авторизирован ли он?

Comment: Конечно, можно. У Вас возникли какие-то проблемы с этим?

Comment: Да, я понимаю как

Comment: Как обратится к запросу пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обратиться к объекту [`request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) так же, как делали это раньше, несмотря на то, что используете [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) (*Class-Based Views*).

***Пример:***

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class PasswordChangeView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

---

**P.S.:** советую обратить внимание на [`LoginRequired`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) mixin.

Comment: В книге написано, что PasswordChangeView наследуется только от FormView. Аа, получается можно самому выбирать, от какого класса наследоваться, как-то не приходило в голову)

Comment: @borrya Вы можете выбрать базовый класс [`View`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#view) или использовать [множество других встроенных представлений](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/#built-in-class-based-views-api).